# Generate a type with the keys and values of an interface as value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface which contains a key and a value and I want to create from that a type with the key as "type" and the value as "data".

*I have this interface*

```
interface NotificationInterface {
    "friends.invite": { userId: number }
    "notification": { url: string }
}
```

*And I want to generate this*

```
type NotificationData =
    | {
          type: "friends.invite"
          data: { userId: number }
      }
    | {
          type: "notification"
          data: { url: string }
      }
```

It is possible to create it automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to transform each member of the interface to the desired shape, then use an [indexed type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content) to get the union:

```
interface NotificationInterface {
    "friends.invite": { userId: number }
    "notification": { url: string }
}
//  And I want to generate this

type Data<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: {
        type: P
        data: T[P]
    }
}[keyof T]

type NotificationData = Data<NotificationInterface>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHszBsBcvogCS408SyA3gLABQyDyARDFMBCACYDOAdKADdgkJgC4qyAK7doRTuJCSAtgCNoyAL51GzEJmy58wQmImSoAG3HcwbEAHNNdLbQD0rhgEEuyIsgDucODIYOjI9hzQ+ChgABbA3HR0YACeAA4oACL4cAA8ACoAfMgAvFTajADaAArIoMgA1hAp6DDI+QC64jT0OoypGeLVFX3InDni+TUdI060GpVNLW2dSbQDKBhYOHgEINlgcKXIB3lbBrvGxKSwiBCFQA)